# javascript force not async

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have had a very simple js function in a cgi for something over 12 years.

The purpose is to launch a program on the client pc by way of a custom url handler. (Which runs a commandline util to perform a TWAIN scan from a document scanner, then http-posts a pdf back to the same cgi on the same server.)

```
<script>
function tsu(e,v) {
  t = window.open("tsu://;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");
  t.close();
  window.location.replace("tsu?"+v);
}
</script>
[...]
<input type="button" value="Scan" onClick="tsu('$TSU_QS','$TSU_VIEW_QS')">
```

$HTTP_HOST, $TSU_QS, and $TSU_VIEW_QS are shell variables in the ksh script cgi that generates this output.

The final window.location.replace() doesn't need to be in synchronous order. That reloads the same cgi (ksh script) that this code appears in, with a new query string which tells it to wait for the expected new pdf to appear on the server filesystem, or a timeout, before it completes loading, so that the redrawn page now includes a thumbnail and link for new scanned-and-uploaded file as soon as it appears.

It's only the close() that needs to be blocked until the open() has launched the external handler. And even that only needs to launch it, not somehow know when it finished. That is being handled during the reload of the current window.

Now, ever since 2016-10-21, when Chrome changed the default behavior of functions to async, this no longer works. The close() happens too soon and the external handler app never happens.

Initially, I tried changing to this:

```
function tsu(e,v) {
  t = window.open("tsu://;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");
  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrom')>-1) {
    t.addEventListener('load',t.close());
  } else t.close();
  window.location.replace("tsu?"+v);
}
```

And it worked in some cases and not others. It made a windows machine work, but still didn't work on an OSX machine.

Debugged/proven by simply commenting out the close, and then the external app runs, but then I have a blank tab I don't want.

(I already know detecting chrome & chromium by name was no long term answer, because eventually all browsers will have the same behavior, but the problem at the moment is, Edge has the addeventlistener function, but it doesn't work right, so I can't simply go by the existence of that feature.)

So it's sort of 3 problems:

1)
I can't figure out how to take this dead simple 3 lines of javascript which has worked in every browser for over 12 years, and convert it to work with the new async/await things.

2)
I also can't figure out how to DETECT when it's even ok to try to use "await" (if that's even what I need), because "typeof await" says "undefined" even on a current Chrome which is exhibiting the new "async-by-default" problem. The feature appears to be new, so it's an error to try to use it on old browsers, yet, none of the pages I found about async/await said anything about how to detect when it's legal to use it and when not.

3)
Maybe there is a way to dispense with the whole tsu() function and just have a plain link or button for the tsu://... , like a mailto: link. And detect that it was clicked some other way to reload the current page?
Then I wouldn't even care about async/await.

[UPDATE]
Incorporating a few things from answers so far:

- just for the purpose of testing, I removed the window.location.replace for now, so no possible issue with replacing the current window at the wrong time.
- no browser test, or functionality test, just do the same thing every time
- used function(){...} in the parameter to addeventlistener

So using the code below, the new tab opens, the external handler app runs, the new window never closes. The console shows "trying addEventListener", but never shows "got event". And this is in both Chrome and Safari on OSX.

So in this version anyway, the event listener isn't working.

```
function tsu(e,v) {
  t = window.open("tsu:;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");
  console.log("trying addEventListener");
  t.addEventListener('load',function() {
    console.log("got event");
    t.close();
  });
  //window.location.replace("tsu?"+v);
}
```

[UPDATE 2]
I still never found a way to make this function work the way it has forever up until Chrome changed in late 2016, but I have found a different way to get what I need, without using this function or one like it at all. Answer below.

Comment: an event listener requires a function as an argument, not the result of calling a function `t.addEventListener('load',function() { t.close(); });` will fix that issue, but that's probably not the only problem in your code - you may also want to put `window.location.replace("/cgi-bin/tsu?"+v);` inside the load event handler

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it didn't work. Someone else said the same thing. Outwardly at least, nothing happens at all when the button is pressed. No _blank window, no external handler app, no reload of the current page. Currently testing on Chrome 56 on OSX.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`/`await` syntax. `window.open` does not return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You won't be able to add event listeners to the `window.open` return value if the URL you've opened is on a different Origin, which seems like the case - I see you've switched `tsu://` and `as://`. If you want to go forward with this approach, both pages need to be on the same Origin.
2. async/await is an abstraction on top of Promises. I don't think it's the best solution to your problem so I won't implement it - but if you want to go with this approach, your listener on load will have to resolve a promise.

Your best bet is a simple hack - just wait a second to close the window.

```
var t = window.open("as://;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");

setTimeout(function() {
  t.close();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: About "tsu://;..."  vs "as:,..." I had mistakenly cut & pasted from a testing version of the script. I edited the question to fix it. Disregard any other forms of the external custom url, just assume "tsu://;host;string" only in all cases. Sorry for the confusion. That was only in there for 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: Now this timout thing is interesting. I tried it, and the external handler launches, but the _blank window never closes.
I tried reducing the value from 1000, as in maybe 1000 is tenths of a second instead of thousandths or something. What's curious is if I use 1, nothing happens, no new window, no external app. If I use 10 or more, the external app runs, but also the new window never closes.

Comment: The window.location.replace does happen in all cases. I have it outside of the setTimeout, after it.

Comment: I think a pause of one second would be about perfect in this case. I know full well the evils of relying on the luck of timing, but the fact is this process needs to fire up a twain scanner and physically scan at least one sheet of paper and then upload a pdf back to the server. Even if you had a very fast workstation, internet from God, and an exotic scanner from NASA that takes a picture of the whole page in a flash like a camera instead of scanning like a scanner, that all still takes longer than a second, and even if it didn't, waiting one second per press of the Scan button would be fine.

Comment: Conversely, if you had a workstation so slow that it took more than a second just to fork the process, it's ok with us to say to the customer, you can't use that particular workstation to do scanning. (and, they still can anyway, because the same cgi also has a way to manually select files to upload, instead of the handy scan button). So really, the dirty hack would be fine.

Comment: Wait, what is this about same origin? Is that my problem? The url opened is "tsu://;host;string" but the new window says "about:blank" in it's address bar, which is basically two different urls, is that a difference in Origin? What does Origin mean in this context?

Comment: Here's some more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

Basically, unless the first page and second page are on the same domain (and protocol! (tsu://)) you won't be able to control the second page with the first

Comment: Interesting. Except, have I mentioned it's already been working for 12 years... ? :)
That is, t.close() worked. Until last week I never tried to use addEventListener before, so no idea if that would have worked before or not. but close() absolutely did.
The window being closed is (was) really about:blank not tsu:foo. But about: is not http: either.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see your attempt:

```
function tsu(e,v) {
  t = window.open("tsu://;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");
  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrom')>-1) {
    t.addEventListener('load',t.close());
  } else t.close();
  window.location.replace("/cgi-bin/tsu?"+v);
}
```

The first and obvious thing is that you did not subscribe to the event, instead you called `t.close()` right away.

Second, why do you try to detect if the browser is a chrome? Subscribing to an event listener IS the right way of doing it, it should work on every browser. If it doesn't work on some browser, that's the browser you want to workaround, not the other ones.

So your function could just be:

```
function tsu(e,v) {
  t = window.open("tsu://;${HTTP_HOST};"+e,"_blank");
  t.addEventListener('load',function() {
      t.close();
      // you need location replace here else the page could be redirected before the popup gets closed
      window.location.replace("/cgi-bin/tsu?"+v);
  });
}
```

After a second thought, it would be better if you could just program the popup window to close itself after load.

Comment: What popup window?
Say I made it pop up a window, in that window, I would still need to launch the external url, so I would have exactly the same problem in the popup that I have now.

I tried this suggested change (the final version you posted above) and it made no difference. On Chrome on OSX, if I comment out the close, then I get a new blank tab and the external handler runs. Uncomment the close, and outwardly at least, nothing happens at all.

Comment: If I make a plain href link, no form, input, button, no javascript, just <a href="tsu://;host;encryptedstring">Click here to scan</a> That launches the external handler with no new blank browser tab to worry about closing. But then I just need some way to reload the current page with the right query string to make it pause while loading until the expected pdf file appears on the filesystem. Otherwise the user hits the link, the scanner runs, but nothing happens on the page to show the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered it myself. Well, I found a *different* answer that accomplishes my ultimate task, but it does not answer the question of "How can I make those 3 lines execute serially today, the way they did for so many years until Oct 2016?".

I just found that if I dispense with the javascript entirely and just use a plain form input button, I get most of the behavior I really want.

The tsu: url launches.
The registered external handler app runs on the client.
The current page displayed in the browser does not change.
There is no new window or tab to worry about closing.

```
<form action="tsu://;host;string"><input type="submit" value="Scan"></form>
```

No tsu(), no onClick.

The problem then is just, if I used this method instead, how can I reload the current page (with a different query string which I'd previously generated in the cgi) whenever that button is pressed?

I tried just adding onClick just to run window.location.replace() instead of tsu(), like this, but it didn't change the current page. The external app launched, so the action=... worked, but the current page didn't reload, so the onClick didn't (appear to) work.

```
<form action="tsu://;host;string"><input type="submit" value="Scan" onClick="window.location.replace('/index.html')"></form>
```

Alternate:

```
<form action="tsu://;host;string"><button onClick="window.location.replace('/index.html')">Scan</button></form>
```

But if I replace the window.location.replace() with just alert(), I DID get the alert, and it happens first, before the action="...".

Strange, but both actions DID happen, so I just tried replacing alert() with setTimeout() (with the reload inside of that) and voila, that finally got me back to where I already was before Chrome decided to break 12 years...ok ok but seriously, I can't say that enough...

**So, final conclusion, THIS works.**

The action=... triggers the external handler app first.
Then a split second later the current browser page reloads to the specified new url (which happens to actually be the same url with new query string).

```
<form action="tsu://;host;string"><button onClick="setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace('other_url.html');},200)">Scan</button></form>
```

And just for completeness, replacing those dummy values, this is the translation of the original posted code at the top of the question, to this new form:

```
<form action="tsu://;${HTTP_HOST};${TSU_QS}","><button onClick="setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace('tsu?${TSU_VIEW_QS}');},200)">Scan</button></form>
```

In the end, I think this is a better way to do what I was doing than what I had been doing. No more opening and then immediately closing a new window. As the users start using it, I'll watch and see if I need to bump that 200 up to 1000 or so.

Thanks for the suggestions and info everyone.